# problem to access node's values in nested foreach loop for XSLT

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

```
<A>
    <B>
        <EO>dummy 1</EO>
        <EF>test 1</EF>
    </B>
    <C>
        <c1>amount</c1>
        <c2>total</c2>
    </C>
    <C>
        <c1>rpm</c1>
        <c2>tax</c2>
    </C>
    
    
    <B>
        <EO>dummy 2</EO>
        <EF>test 2</EF>
    </B>
    
    <C>
        <c1>amount 2</c1>
        <c2>total 2</c2>
    </C>
    <C>
        <c1>rpm 2</c1>
        <c2>tax 2</c2>
    </C>
    
</A>
```

Above is sample XML And I am using below code to access nodes in XSLT,

```
<xsl:for-each select="A/B"> 
    <div>
        <xsl:value-of select="EO"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="EF"/>
    </div>

    <xsl:for-each select="../C">    
        <div>
            <xsl:value-of select="c1"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="c2"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

B node is giving proper value as it is in for each loop but while accessing second foreach loop, I am getting all "C" tag values. What I need is it should access all "C" nodes which is immediate below to current B node. Kindly suggest if any solution available for this.

Comment: This is not XML: `<1>amount</1>`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k : yeah right about XML, and what if we need to access all C nodes below B node?

Comment: issue resolved by using,  <xsl:for-each select="../following-sibling::C[position() &lt;= 2]">

Comment: That would be a good solution if you know there never will be more than 2. A better solution (in XSLT 2.0) would **group** the nodes - see demo here:https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS2B6Q

Answer (score 0):

> access only 1 "C" node which is immediate to current B node

Try:

```
<xsl:for-each select="A/B"> 
    <div>
        <xsl:value-of select="EO"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="EF"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::C[1]"/>
    </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```